# Example of the undecidability of higher-order unification

Tags: logic, theorem-proving, unification, typed-lambda-calculus, undecidable-instances

Could you demonstrate the undecidability of higher-order unification by one example?
For example, please show by one example that unification in lambda-calculus is undecidable.